# escape metacharacters [ ] re2 in Google spreadsheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, re2

I want use the function [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) in a Google spreadsheets for retrive a string between brackets.

ex.
in the cell A1 I have the text: `qwertyui (asdfghjk)`
I need the text `asdfghjk`.

The function `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\(([A-Za-z /]+)\)")` works finely but when I have a text like `qwertyui ([asdfghjk])` the function doesn't return nothing because the regular expression that I use does not have the square brackets.

I tried to add the characters "[" and "]" but they are metacharacters. I used the notation `\[` (and `\]`) but don't works.
Google spreadsheets use regular expression re2. Is the notation correct?

Anyone know how to escape from metacharacters (or where I am wrong)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"\(([A-Za-z\[\] /]+)\)"`  or ("smart" placement) `"\(([][A-Za-z /]+)\)"`.

[image]

or

[image]

However, since you are just extracting any text inside parentheses, you can make use of a ***negated*** character class `[^()]` that matches any character but a `(` and `)`.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\(([^()]+)\)")
```

[image]

Comment: don't works. an error was reported: Error
Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "\(([][A-Za-z /]+)\)" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "[Category 1] ([Other 1])".

Comment: Does it just mean you want to get a substring inside parentheses? It is much easier to do with a *negated* character class `[^()]`: `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\(([^()]+)\)")`

Comment: Hi stribizhev, all your solutions are correct but I detect that don't works if the text in the cell is a result of the function "importRange". Maybe is a bug. It's strange, for the text "Category 1 (Other 1)" all works finely. Thanks a lot however.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually just simplify it to this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\((.*\))")
```